# How to change Gradle download location

Tags: build, gradle

I am starting to learn gradle.
However when I am building Spring with Gradle; it downloads the dependency jars to

```
C:\Users\UserName\.gradle
```

Is there any way I can specify Gradle to download the dependency jars to a specific location?
Just like I can specify repository location in Maven.

System information:
Windows 7 64bit
Gradle version 1.0

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You can set the `GRADLE_USER_HOME` environment variable, `gradle.user.home` system property, or `--gradle-user-home` command line parameter.

Comment: Using GRADLE_USER_HOME is not work for me(gradle still load wrapper in to the old folder).Please help me how to run --gradle-user-home command line parameter.

Comment: this might be helpful for people new to gradle. I also need to re run ./gradlew installDist in my project folder to re-download everything to the new GRADLE_USER_HOME

Comment: Setting the gradle.user.home property in the gradle.properties does not change the location.

Comment: This doesn't change the location but the GRADLE_HOME variable finds mention in all newly created/imported projects. So whatever folder you mention inside that variable will have the 'scum in the name of gradle' downloaded there. So it won't clog up your C anymore. What a shithole of a open source IDE this is!

Answer (score 10):

On android studio just go to **File > Settings > Build Execution, Deployment > Gradle > Service directory path** choose directory what you want.

Comment: misleading answer

Comment: Work for me !!!! - on Android Studio 191.6010548-windows - Thank you very much

Comment: Worked for me after restarting the PC.

Comment: I tried this, it works only existing project. New project uses the default path. I found  setting system environment variable `GRADLE_USER_HOME` as custom location, it did work, and setting panel shows the location as default.

Comment: This worked for me. What about visual code?

Answer (score 5):

You can add following line to your `gradle.properties`:

```
systemProp.gradle.user.home=/tmp/changed-gradle
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also try to go in eclipse at window ->preferences -> gradle and change the directory there

Answer (score 4):

Steps:

- Set the GRADLE_USER_HOME environment variable to new path
- On android studio just go to File > Settings > Build Execution, Deployment > Gradle > Service directory path choose directory what you want.
- Restart the PC (important step, no one mentioned this surprisingly)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run gradle tasks through IDE then:
You can also set in intelliJ editor>File>settings:

[image: IntelliJ editor]

Then restart the IDE.

If you want to run gradle tasks through command line then you have to set GRADLE_USER_HOME in environment system variables. Then restart the pc as others also said.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gradle plugin in your eclipse and trying to import the gradle project than your gradle home is set to

C:\Users\UserName.gradle

In some cases your import build model will not work because of your user directory permission issue.

In this case you can copy your .gradle directory from below path

```
C:\Users\UserName\**.gradle**
```

paste into some directory where you have all permission and import the project.

In my case i moved my .gradle dir to z drive and than imported the project than made build model and it worked.