# Intellij IDEA classpath.jar causing problems

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, classpath

When I run unit tests in Intellij IDEA, it is creating a jar called casspath0.jar. In that jar is a Manifest file with the classpath needed for the test to run. How can I make intellij not do that?

More Details:

I am running Intellij IDEA 15.0.4, Java 1.8.0_77, Windows 7. The project is a gradle project that was imported into the IDE.

When running a unit test in debug mode, if I run

```
System.getProperty("java.class.path")
```

I see something like

```
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\classpath0.jar;C:\Users\me\.IntelliJIdea15\system\groovyHotSwap\gragent.jar
```

and that is it. The rest of the classpath is in that classpath0.jar.

No one else in my office has this problem and this is a very old project (10+ years) that a lot of people (25+) work on. They all have the full classpath under that property rather than in a temporary jar. I speculate that there must be some setting that I am missing. This is causing problems with me not being able to successfully run our unit tests.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the cause of this. It has to do with the 'dynamic.classpath' setting in intellij IDEA. [What does the dynamic.classpath flag do? (IntelliJ project settings)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853540/what-does-the-dynamic-classpath-flag-do-intellij-project-settings)

As for my problem about unit tests, I guess I am going to change where gradle downloads the dependencies to try and make my classpath shorter. [How to change Gradle download location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016681/how-to-change-gradle-download-location).

Short of that I will have to dig into the library that is causing me problems and see if I can fix that.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem when starting up Glassfishv4, with a similar exception. To fix it, find domain.xml and remove the following line:

```
<jvm-options>...system\groovyHotSwap\gragent.jar</jvm-options>
```

After that, Glassfish starts without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

After uninstalling and reinstalling IntelliJ at a different location, I had an error on server (Weblogic) startup that I think had nothing to do with the fact that it was a WL server.  It complained it could not find C:\<path>\gragent.jar.  One of my projects had .groovy files in it and also I was running a debug session at times too.  Discovered that there was a hard-coded (ugh!) path reference to that .jar file in my workspace.xml file at C:\<sourcepath>\<project>\.idea.  In the entry <configuration default="false" name="<name>" type="WebLogic Instance" factoryName="Local"... > in <option name="COMMON_VM_ARGUMENTS"...> in the value="...", the RHS value was a hard path to gragent.jar.  I had to update the path to the file's new location.  Didn't need to re-start IntelliJ, I was able to save the file and try to run the server again from withing IntelliJ and it came up w/o that error.