# Cannot import Java classes from a previously built JAR

Tags: java, maven, jar, protocol-buffers

I am trying to implement a shell script that generates the Java classes for a given set of Protobuf files. The generated classes are then grouped into a JAR which is to be imported by any Java project  that needs to use these protobuf generated classes or gRPC stubs.

The script roughly looks like bellow:

```
# Generate java classes from .proto files
protoc -I ${PROTO_REPO_PATH} 
    --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc-java=$GEN_GRPC_JAVA_PATH \
    --grpc-java_out=$JAVA_OUT --java_out=$JAVA_OUT \
    $FILES
  
JAR_FILE="$JAVA_OUT/$SERVICE_NAME-$API_VERSION.jar"

# Create JAR from generated classes
jar cf "$JAR_FILE" -C "$JAVA_OUT" .
  
# Install JAR in local repository
  mvn install:install-file -Dfile=$JAR_FILE -Dpackaging=jar -DgroupId=foo.grpc -DartifactId=$SERVICE_NAME-proto -Dversion=1.0

# Clean generated java code
rm -r $JAVA_OUT
```

After execution, the JAR is present in `~/.m2/repository` and, using `jar tf foo-service-1.0.jar`, I verified that all the generated classes are inside it.

Yet I cannot import any of those classes in a Java project on any IDE I tried (i.e. IntelliJ, VScode). The JAR appears  empty inside the IDE browser yet autocompletion works when importing the parrent packages but fails when trying to import a specific class.

I tried proposed answers on this similar but different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39703092/what-causes-jar-files-to-appear-empty-to-intellij-idea) but without any success.

Comment: Show output from `jar tvf your.jar`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a compile step to make .class from .jar. Are there any .class files in the jar or only .java?

You need something like the following run from the base of the package tree:

```
javac ./
```

Between the protoc and jar steps

Answer (score 0):

Figured the problem was due to missing required dependencies in the produced JAR (i.e. "protobuf-java", "grpc-protobuf", "grpc-stub"). Issue solved by using the "protoc-jar-maven-plugin" which generates the Java classes from the .proto files and include the said dependencies in the JAR, making it possible to use the generated classes that are inside.